# Get right data in Foreach loop inside For loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I need to insert multiple shops with selected subcategories, shop data in one table and subcategories in second. And when i do that with 'foreach' loop inside 'for' loop same subcategory data is inserted n times (depending on how many shops there is). When I put foreach loop outside for loop then $md5c unique id is inserting just first one. How to fix that?

```
$input_count = count($_POST['npm']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $input_count; $i++) {
    $a = uniqid(about);
    $b = uniqid (about, true);
    $c = uniqid (rand(), true);
    $md5c = md5($c);
    $n = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['npm'][$i]);
    $a = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['apm'][$i]);
    $c = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mipm'][$i]);
    $wh = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rv'][$i]);
    $t = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ktf'][$i]);
    $mob = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ktm'][$i]);
    $mail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kea'][$i]);
    $con = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ipko'][$i]);

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO shops (id, n, a, c, wh, tel, mob, mail, con) VALUES ('$md5c', '$n','$a','$c','$wh','$t','$mob','$mail','$con')";
    $rs2=mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

    foreach ( $_POST['subcat'] as $key=>$value ) {
        $values = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        $query3="INSERT INTO sc (subcat_id,shop_id) VALUES ($values,'$md5c')";
        $rs3=mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: use foreach outside and inside that foreach use $md5c = md5(uniqid (rand(), true));

Comment: What do you want to fix?

Comment: Also How do you determine which category relate to a specific shop?

Comment: Can you please add the print_r($_POST); to your question

Comment: @Sibiraj PR - with your code i get different ids

Comment: Yes i understand the issue there. Can you add print_r($_POST).

Comment: @Sergey - i want that specified $md5c in both tables and that should connect shops with categories

Comment: How to you determine on form wich Category relate to Shop? Or you want set up same categories for all shops?

Comment: @svemirac add print_r($_POST) result to the question

Comment: every shop should have multiple different categories. shops can be added dynamically via jquery. input fields for category chekboxes look like this `<input type='checkbox' name='cat[]' value='$id'>`

Comment: @Sibiraj PR - its part of much bigger form so it would not help much

Comment: @svemirac atleast print_r($_POST['subcat']) this one

Comment: here it is: `Array ( [0] => 35 [1] => 34 [2] => 25 [3] => 26 ) Array ( [0] => 35 [1] => 34 [2] => 25 [3] => 26 ) Array ( [0] => 35 [1] => 34 [2] => 25 [3] => 26 ) Array ( [0] => 35 [1] => 34 [2] => 25 [3] => 26 )`

Answer (score 0):

you can try storing your $values in a new array

so before the two loops you have to define $md5cArray = [], then start the first loop , store each value in the array like $md5cArray[] = md5c;

start the second loop outside the first one with the same structure, and since arrays are sorted you can do this:

in the second loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_POST['subcat']); $i++) {

    $values = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $query3="INSERT INTO sc (subcat_id,shop_id) VALUES ({$_POST['subcat'][inner][second-inner]}, {$md5c[$i]})";
    $rs3 = mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());

}
```

you have to edit the first element in values to the correct structure you have.

your final code should be like this

```
$input_count = count($_POST['npm']);
$md5cArray = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $input_count; $i++) {
$a = uniqid(about);
$b = uniqid (about, true);
$c = uniqid (rand(), true);
$md5c = md5($c);
$md5cArray[] = md5($c); // new array
$n = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['npm'][$i]);
$a = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['apm'][$i]);
$c = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mipm'][$i]);
$wh = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rv'][$i]);
$t = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ktf'][$i]);
$mob = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ktm'][$i]);
$mail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kea'][$i]);
$con = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ipko'][$i]);

$query2 = "INSERT INTO shops (id, n, a, c, wh, tel, mob, mail, con) VALUES ('$md5c', '$n','$a','$c','$wh','$t','$mob','$mail','$con')";
$rs2=mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
```

}

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_POST['subcat']); $i++) {
    $values = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $query3="INSERT INTO sc (subcat_id, shop_id) VALUES ("{$_POST['subcat'][$i]}","{$md5c[$i]}")";
    $rs3=mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());}
```

Comment: I dont understand this. Can you explain more? How values are inserted with this code?

Comment: first print_r($_POST['subcat']), let say you have an inner array, your code should be like $_POST['subcat']['ebooks'][$i] or $_POST['subcat'][$i]['ebooks'], it depends on your structure. 

got it?

Comment: no :D, dont get that multi arrays. is there some example that you can point me to? thank you. my print_r displays arrays of category ids like this: `Array ( [0] => 35 [1] => 34 [2] => 25 [3] => 26 )`

Comment: haha, i edited the code, take a look at it , try it now as is. it should work now, you have to look for something similar actually i don't have any other samples. :/

Comment: it says error on insert code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Comment: try to replace the second loop now, what is the line number for this error?

Comment: its working with single quotes but now in sc table shop_id is just one number or letter

Comment: $query3="INSERT INTO sc (subcat_id, shop_id) VALUES ("{$_POST['subcat'][$i]}","{$md5cArray[$i]}")";

Comment: `$query3="INSERT INTO sc (subcat_id, shop_id) VALUES ('{$_POST['subcat'][$i]}','{$md5cArray[$i]}')";` this doesnt display erros but inserts category ids just for one shop

Comment: then am done here, now you have to check $_POST['subcat'] if its storing the right ids, try to print it before the second loop, see whats missing, i can't debug your code any farther. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

use **foreach ( $_POST['subcat'][$i] as $key => $value ) {**

```
$input_count = count($_POST['npm']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $input_count; $i++) {
    $a = uniqid(about);
    $b = uniqid (about, true);
    $c = uniqid (rand(), true);
    $md5c = md5($c);
    $n = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['npm'][$i]);
    $a = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['apm'][$i]);
    $c = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mipm'][$i]);
    $wh = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rv'][$i]);
    $t = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ktf'][$i]);
    $mob = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ktm'][$i]);
    $mail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kea'][$i]);
    $con = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ipko'][$i]);

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO shops (id, n, a, c, wh, tel, mob, mail, con) VALUES ('$md5c', '$n','$a','$c','$wh','$t','$mob','$mail','$con')";
    $rs2=mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

    foreach ( $_POST['subcat'][$i] as $key => $value ) {
        $values = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        $query3="INSERT INTO sc (subcat_id,shop_id) VALUES ($values,'$md5c')";
        $rs3=mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```